# The graph obtained has $|F|$ cycles?

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G = (V(G),Y)$ be a forest. Let $F$ a edge set such ends of each edge of $F$ are connected in $G$ and $F$ not contains cycle. I know that graph $G' = (V(G), Y \cup F)$ contains at least $|F|$ cycles. Moreover, each cycle in $G'$ contains exactly one edge of $F$.
Is true $G'$ contains exactly $|F|$ cycles?

Comment: $F$ and $Y$ are disjoint?

Comment: anyway, take a line graph on 4 points, and 2 additional edges. You obtain 3 cycles

Comment: Yes, $F$ and $Y$ are disjoint.